# Google Mobile Ads (Admob) - Switching Between Test & Prod?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm using the Google Mobile Ads (Admob) asset for my Unity mobile game to display a bottom banner ad during the gameplay.

During development, I of course used test IDs for the banner ad as it is against their terms of service to use production ads while testing.

However, I recently switched those IDs to production versions because I just released the initial version of my game in the Google Play Store. But now I'm wondering if every single time I want to work on updates or bugs that I need to switch out those IDs. Is this what everyone else does? Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of Options that you can try out which works with your project

1. You can add your test devices on admobUI
   -> https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433
2. Use library like ( firebase remote config / or use your own server apis) to deploy test Ads for specific release ( take a look at below question for example )
   [Problem with fetching from firebase remote config for Ads Id on unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165141/problem-with-fetching-from-firebase-remote-config-for-ads-id-on-unity)

Review google video for more information - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gsd26EuSg4g